# What is a pixel (px) in CSS?

Tags: css, graphics

I am reading an ASP.NET book and it refers to CSS files and talks about pixels. But I never understood it from a resolution, layout, etc. point of view. For example, what does the following mean in CSS file definition?

```
#header
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `0px` should just be `0`, it's the same size in any unit. :)

Answer (score 35):

This is a little beyond where you might be at the moment, but a CSS pixel is *not necessarily* exactly the same size as a single pixel on your display. According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#pixel-units):

> If the pixel density of the output device is very different from that of a typical computer display, the user agent should rescale pixel values. It is recommended that the reference pixel be the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's length.

So if you have one of those incredibly expensive extra-high-resolution displays that doesn't count as “typical”, the browser and/or OS may choose to redefine what a “pixel” is.

The useful definition for a ‘px’ as far as CSS authoring is concerned is: a ‘px’ is the quantity of length equal to the pixel in an unscaled HTML <img> or CSS ‘background-image’.

Comment: Thanks bobince. This question needs two answers: the basic explanation (provided by CMS and others) that most readers are interested in, and the technical answer explaining that a pixel is a relative (not absolute) unit, and that CSS pixels are not necessarily the same as device pixels.

Comment: The pixel unit defined by your quote refers to the *reference* pixel, which may not even be related to the "px" unit in CSS anymore.  CSS 2.1 has redefined "1px" to be equal to "0.75pt" at all times.  It also defines that on low resolution devices (like traditional monitors) *all* absolute units should be adjusted so that "1px" should be the closest multiple in device pixels to the reference pixel.  So "1cm" is not necessarily one centimeter anymore but it *is* "37.8px" since that is how the px unit is calculated.  [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units)

Comment: +1 for that reference to the spec. I've never seen that before :)

Answer (score 23):

A pixel is generally thought of as the smallest single component of a digital image.

The number of pixels in an image is called resolution.

The screen resolution is the number of distinct pixels in each dimension that can be displayed by your screen.

In the css snippet that you posted you're applying 0 pixels of margin and padding to the element with id="header".

[image]
<sub>(source: [functionx.com](http://www.functionx.com/win32/images/pixel1.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 7):

"[A pixel is not a little square](http://alvyray.com/Memos/CG/Microsoft/6_pixel.pdf)" is a good discussion on what a pixel is.

It might not be relevant to your specific question, but if anyone else finds this thread for a computer graphics related problem, this is great reading.

Comment: Great that someone enjoyed it!
When the topic of the post was changed it was even more off topic than when I wrote it :)

Comment: That link is broken, but it is here now: http://alvyray.com/memos/6_pixel.pdf [Summary: A pixel is not a little square, nor a little rectangle; it's a *point* sample.]

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected the link in the post too.

Comment: Some of that information is very dated.  Many scanners, cameras, displays, and some printers do indeed use little squares.  Alvy's point is that you should think of these things as point samples because the math works better that way, and it does.  But to insist that a pixel is a point sample is not consistent with today's physical devices.  Point samples are useful and important and indeed they should not be confused with little squares.  But pixel != point sample.

Comment: I partially agree. What is read from a sensor is most likely not point sample (most likely not a little square either though). I believe the right thing to do for makers of devices is to convert their raw sensor data to an as accurate as possible representation of point samples when storing it in an image format. In that way they can ensure that programs manipulating the image without knowing anything about the device it was captured on can do as good as possible.

Comment: Just noticed that the author is actually a co-founder of Pixar!

Comment: Quoting a random guy at reddit `This is from 1997. Now that LCDs are ubiquitous, pixels literally are little squares. For a 3LCD projector with perfect convergence the model is exactly accurate.` --gfody. But CSS pixels might be different in that they are scaled in high dpi displays.

Comment: I still think it's a harmful way of thinking of pixels as squares. As soon as you look to transform the image (scale, rotate etc) thinking of it in terms of squares causes problems and artifacts. Also, for LCD projectors very often the pixels are split up into RGB as separate regions which is something the little square model doesn't replicate. Something like cleartype in windows is using this in the reconstruction to get more detail. I think the right way is not considering the little squares (if they are there) until you reconstruct your image for a specific device.

Answer (score 5):

It means a dimension, measured in pixels on-screen. E.g.

```
width: 200px;
```

means an element is 200 pixels wide.

A pixel is a "PICture ELement", meaning one coloured dot on the screen, probably much like the period at the end of this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A [pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel) is a single dot on the screen.  Your example sets the  element named `header` with no padding or  margin.  To understand this you'll also need to understand the [CSS box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for page layout.

Comment: No, that's not true. On screens with lower resolutions, it is one pixel on the screen, but on high-DPI screens it can be 2×2 or mode physical pixels.

Answer (score 0):

A pixel is a unit of measurement, at least, in regards to CSS. There is also pt, em, percentage... there are a few others. Each have their strengths.

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) is chock full of references, check the one on [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

I recommend downloading Firebug and experiment with changing the pixel width/height.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, a pixel is simply a measurable unit that relates directly to the electronic display of data - a single pixel is the smallest an object on screen can be. The greater the screen resolution, the more pixels it can represent.

A note on the example given - a value of 0px is actually unnecessary as a zero value, and is better represented in CSS as just a 0 (it could equally be 0% or 0em, they all mean the same).