# JavaScript custom alert box - innerHeight

Tags: javascript

I've found this code `dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px"` on a tutorial on how to create custom alert boxes in JS. And I just wanted to know what does `px` in the code do? Any explanation? I thought it was a string. I know that it is used to apply an event of a function on the entire document (height), but I wanted to know the use "px".

Comment: Back to school to learn the basics. Did you try to search for "CSS px"?

Comment: `px` is a measurement unit, where `winH` is a number of pixels for setting up height of `dialogoverlay` element, so if you want to set height using JavaScript, you've to concatenate height number with `px`.

Comment: `px` is [CSS unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a pixel (px) in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600374/what-is-a-pixel-px-in-css)